# Reduce the size of text in angularjs when line breaks?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a responsive app for desktop and mobile.

In the app i have a div which randomly shows texts of all kinds of lengths.
I want to do the following:

If the line breaks because the length of the text is too wide for the width of that div, i want the font-size to reduce itself (I am using em's in my app).

Is it something i need to build directive for it? is it something that was built and used wildly?

Comment: that doesn't sound like something that is up to angular to solve;  I think the css tag is the most important one here.

Comment: Which means what? The text will break to two lines, because of the length of the texts, isn't it up to javascript to see the current length of my text, the current width of my div, to do something that will lower my em's?

Comment: maybe javascript, but not angular, but ideally CSS.  if you were truncating your **data**, then you could have a filter to make that change, but all angular can really do to help in this case would be to provide a variable that you can use to decide which **style** to use, which is really the job of CSS.

Comment: You could simply do this with media queries or if you need to, use some script like http://simplefocus.com/flowtype/

Comment: After I re-read question I understand that is not you need, but anyway http://plnkr.co/edit/ajaWYxiwrGdxxO31iDCi?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing a robust solution for this problem is going to be non-trivial. As far as I know, there's no way to tell whether a line of text breaks. However, we do know the criteria for line breaking is the width of the text being wider than the element, accounting for padding.

The Canvas API has a method called [`measureText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/measureText) which can be used to measure a string, using a given context with a font and size set. If you spoof the settings of the element with a canvas, then you can measure the text with the canvas and adjust the size until it fits without overflowing.

I've written up a rough implementation of the way I would tackle this.

```
function TextScaler(element) {
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
      context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var scaler = {};

  scaler.copyProps = function() {
    var style   = element.style.fontStyle,
        family  = element.style.fontFamily,
        size    = element.style.fontSize,
        weight  = element.style.fontWeight,
        variant = element.style.fontVariant;

    context.font = [style, variant, weight, size, family].join(' ');
  };

  scaler.measure = function(text) {
    text = text || element.innerText;
    return context.measureText(text);
  };

  scaler.overflows = function() {
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(element),
        paddingLeft = style['padding-left'],
        paddingRight = style['padding-right'],
        width = style.width - paddingLeft - paddingRight;

    return scaler.measure() > width;
  };

  scaler.decrease = function() {
    // decrease font size by however much
  };

  scaler.auto = function(retries) {
    retries = retries || 10;

    if(retries <= 0) {
      scaler.apply();
      console.log('used all retries');
    }

    if(scaler.overflows()) {
      scaler.decrease();
      scaler.auto(retries - 1);
    } else {
      console.log('text fits');
      scaler.apply();
    }
  };

  scaler.apply = function() {
    // copy the properties from the context
    // back to the element
  };

  return scaler;
}
```

After you've sorted out some of the blank details there, you'd be able to use the function something like this:

```
var element = document.getElementById('');
var scaler = TextScaler(element);
scaler.auto();
```

If it doesn't manage to decrease it within 10 retries, it will stop there. You could also do this manually.

```
while(scaler.overflows()) {
  scaler.decrease();
}
scaler.apply();
```

You'd probably want some fairly fine tuned logic for handling the decrease function. It might be easiest to convert the ems to pixels, then work purely with integers.

This API could quite trivially be wrapped up as a directive, if you want to use this with Angular. I'd probably tackle this with two attribute directives.

```
<div text-scale retries="10">Hello world</div>
```

---

Of course, if it's not important that all the text is there onscreen, then you can just use the `text-overflow: ellipsis` CSS property.